# Function with optional argument that depends on other argument

Tags: functions, replacement

I'm trying to do a simple thing: I want the optional argument to depend on another argument, i.e.

`f[x_,y_:Subscript[m,x]] := x-y`

This should give: `f[z] = z-Subscript[m,z]` and `f[z,y] = z-y`

Any idea how I can get this to work? I've tried `f[x_,y_:>Subscript[m,x]] := x-y`

Comment: Write separate definitions for ``f``? That is: ``f[x_] := x - Subscript[m, x]; f[x_, y_] := x - y``

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use two definitions:

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_] := x - Subscript[m, x]
f[x_, y_] := x - y

f[z]        (* Out: z - Subscript[m, z]*)
f[z, y]     (* Out: -y + z *)
```

Comment: In the case of a more complicated function, one could use `f[x_]:=f[x,Subscript[m,x]]` to avoid duplicate code.